# Excel 2013 Changes cell properties to date by itself

Tags: excel

I use Excel 2013 on my computer using my server,

I´ve made a document with all the right settings for the cells

Still somehow all cells change to date, this can be instant or take a while to happen.

When i close the document after saving and reopening later all cells are sometimes set to DATE

I might have enabled a setting wich might does this but are unable to find it or find a solution for this problem

I use excel a lot so this can be a huge disadvantage on my work.

For example: my server screen turned black, so i re-entered it with remote desktop, and suddenly all cells where set to DATE

I've looked around for a solution for this but wasn't able to find one.

Comment: I know you say you have formatted them so you have not left them as general.  But try [this](http://superuser.com/questions/445407/disable-autoformat-in-excel-2010/445421#445421) out anyways.

Comment: Thank you i will try this, and i will send a reply when i know if it worked.

Comment: No, that caused other problems. I couldn't change a former document, so I had to change it back.

Comment: I think @GarysStudent may have the right idea

Answer (score 0):

This usually results from a corrupt **Style**  Check and, if necessary, correct your Styles.

Comment: Well this changing to date by itself isnt somthing wich happens like all the time, sometimes it happens in 1 hour and sometimes a month later their suddenly on date, the only style i use is a black border and i even made a whole new document to hope to solve it but it didnt.